# Why is a single inline French quote with csquotes causing all the following punctuation to have extra spacing?

Tags: spacing, punctuation, polyglossia, csquotes, french

I'm pretty new to LaTeX, so take it easy on me.

I'm trying to include a (single) French phrase in a (short, simple) document — and I want to get it right, more as a learning exercise, than because it really matters that much in this context.

Some googling (and tons of tex.se posts) have basically led me to the following combination of tool, environment, and packages: 1. [luaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luatex), rendering a 2. [`\documentclass[…]{apa}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apa-style) article, using 3. [`{polyglossia}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polyglossia) and 4. [`{csquotes}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csquotes) to get beautiful French and a blockquote:

[image]

Unfortunately, as shown above, while the `\foreignquote{french}{La propriété, c'est le vol!}` works as intended, it seems to leave the *punctuation* settings screwed up for the rest of the document:

1. Colons and semicolons, after that first `\foreignquote` (slash the implied `\foreignlanguage`), continue to be ‘french-spaced’ throughout the document;
2. I'm very puzzled by the documentation on `autopunct`, but that, also, seems to be behaving strangely — despite my `american` setting, the periods remain stubbornly outside of the quote-marks.

---

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[man]{apa}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{french}

\usepackage[autostyle,autopunct,csdisplay,french=guillemets]{csquotes}
\MakeAutoQuote{“}{”}
\MakeAutoQuote*{‘}{’}
\MakeForeignQuote{french}{«}{»}

% ...

\begin{document}
\EnableQuotes
\ldots\ and to the passion of his writings. He proceeds to cast doubt on many popularization of Proudhon's work, including the famous «La propriété, c'est le vol!»: \blockquote{It is only by reading Proudhon carefully — and fully — that it is possible to understand what he meant by “property” and why he regarded it as “theft”. A false impression of Proudhon's views on this, as well as on the other matters, is derived from such dicta.}

Throughout the work, Schapiro counter-asserts many other viewpoints that he feels are over-represented in both contemporary and later analyses: that Proudhon was a revolutionary (at least in the traditional, violent sense); that Proudhon was of, or for, the masses, as represented by the working-class; even that Proudhon was against statist violence \ldots
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is this bug here: https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/182. With babel there is no problem, so I would suggest to use `\usepackage[french,english]{babel}` instead of polyglossia.

Comment: Thanks, @UlrikeFischer! `:+1:`'d, and I'll follow along there. I just assumed I was a foolish noob, glad to hear it's “should work!” <3